# R: Error when deleting an element from a vector

Tags: r

I made a very basic for loop and if statement condition function but every time I match every 2nd element in the variable "words" to the vector input "t", I want to completely remove that matching element out.

```
matching <- function (t, words){

  for (i in 1:length(t)) {
    if (t[i] == words[2]){
      t[i] <- NULL
    }

  }
  t

}
```

But if I input stuff like `t <- c("Where", "is", "the", "money", "here")`
and call that function with matching(t, c("is", "the")), the function breaks.
"Error in t[i] <- NULL : replacement has length zero" 
How do I fix this problem? I would want to get the output with

```
[1] "Where" "is" "money" "here"
```

and basically I want it to work for ANY input I put into this function..
Also I want to find ways without using special functions like remove() or anything like that..

EDIT: No grep, paste, gsub, remove etc... NO SPECIAL R FUNCTIONS

Comment: Why `is` is included in the output? It should remove both `is` and `the` right ? Maybe something like `t[!grepl(paste(word, collapse = "|"), t)]` or `grep(paste(word, collapse = "|"), t, invert = T, value = T)`?

Comment: Do you want to remove only the second element from `words` ? Should `"is"` be kept as it is and only `"the"` should be removed ?

Comment: Yeah only the 2nd element in words. The "is" should be kept it is.

Comment: The functions you mentioned are not "special" in any way. However, you can't assign `NULL` to an element of a vector; usa `NA` instead and at the end return `t[!is.na(t)]`.

Comment: Is this a homework task or something? What's wrong with `grep`? What about `t[ !( t %in% words[2] ) ]`?

Comment: Just use `t[i] <- ""` instead of `t[i] <- NULL`

Comment: I'd suggest `for`, `:`, `if`, and `length` are all just as "special" as `grep`.

Comment: t[i] <- "" just adds a "" in the output and I want that completely blank. I guess the closest answer so far is given by rosscova. Okay, not special but basically I prefer knowing the hard way first before I apply grep because grep solves this problem in 1 minute..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
t <- c("Where", "is", "the", "money", "here")
word <- c("is", "the")

matching <- function (t, words){
  # initialize vector
  tmp <- c()
  for (i in 1:length(t)) {
       if (t[i] != words[2]){
        tmp <- c(tmp, t[i])
      }

   }
  return(tmp)
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I didn't realize that I could have done this backwards and then assign it to a brand new vector. And why did I get downvotes when I actually did something this time... I don't get it..

Comment: I don't know about your down votes. I just recently started actively participating, but the [voting section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) in the help center probably might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remove only 2nd element of `word` from `t` , we can try using `grep` along with its `invert` and `value` property

```
grep(word[2], t, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
#[1] "Where" "is"    "money" "here"
```

where

```
t <- c("Where", "is", "the", "money", "here")
word <- c("is", "the")
```

Here `word` are the words which you want to remove from `t`. The `invert` property of `grep` returns the value which do not match.

---

**EDIT** : As per OP's comment no 'special' functions should be used. Here is a try with continuing the `for` loop

```
matching <- function (t, words){
  flag = FALSE
  for (i in 1:length(t)) {
    if (t[i] == words[2]){
      t[i] <- t[i+1]
      flag = TRUE
   }
    if(flag) {
      t[i] <- t[i+1]
    }
  }
  t[-length(t)]
}
```

Sample Output :

```
matching(t, word)
#[1] "Where" "is"    "money" "here"
```

Comment: I can't solve this problem without any other way? I am not allowed to use grep, gsub, remove or anything like that...

Comment: If I could use those, I mean, I wouldn't ask this problem to be honest.,,